# Unable to initialize plugins with jQuery(document).ready after minified code?

Tags: jquery, minify, superfish

trying to consolidate my JS so I've got a number of jQuery Plugins such as Superfish minified within one JS file and just below, in the same file, I initialize the various plugins within jQuery(document).ready, but console is showing undefined errors such as:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'superfish'

However when I initialize outside of jQuery(document).ready everything is fine!

Any clues whats wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

check your code with JSLint first, maybe you forgot a semicolon or something.

Comment: JSLint shows many _"Expected ';' and instead saw '}'_ warnings from  the minified plugins. However as mentioned everything initializes without error in console when I _dont_ use jQuery(document).ready closure :( Anyway heres my file on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/sZCZdf4j)  Appreciate your assistance !